# How to get image url which is inside a div

Tags: javascript, html

Is this possible to get the image URL which is inside a DIV

For example

```
<div id="smallImage" style="display: block;">
<img width="270" height="270" alt="Vitra" name="large" src="http://example.com/598441_m2.jpg" style="display: block;">
</div>
```

I want to read this in a javascript . i.e. in newImg.src

```
<script>
var newImg = new Image();
newImg.src = " ?? ";
</script>
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks
Sheikh

Comment: Are you trying to get the URL or set it? Your JavaScript snippet is somewhat contrary to your question.

Comment: @WebUser User They are doing both?

Comment: I am  trying to get the URL. I want to know what should I write to get the URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var myImgSrc = document.getElementById("smallImage").getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src;
```

[You may find further information about document here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `document.querySelectorAll` like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c9yP5/).

Answer (score 1):

If not using jQuery - http://jsfiddle.net/FyBbY/

```
var image_source = document.querySelector('#smallImage img').src

var newImg = new Image();
newImg.src= image_source;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
newImg.src = document.getElementsByName("large")[0].src;
```

Add this line and it will work, You don't have to use jQuery just for this.

So complete answers is as following.

```
<script>
var newImg = new Image();
newImg.src = document.getElementsByName("large")[0].src;
</script>
```